# Can I connect Ubuntu to Bluetooth Speaker?

Tags: bluetooth, music

Can I stream music from my Ubuntu laptop to a JBL Pulse2 bluetooth speaker?

Ubuntu's listing of bluetooth devices shows my phone, but doesn't find the speaker. I got my android phone to work with the speaker and the speaker manual mentions only about connecting a phone/tablet to it.

Comment: Did you put the speaker to Bluetooth pairing mode while seeking for a new device in the Bluetooth indicator?

Comment: @Takkat I pressed the bluetooth symbol on the speaker and after that my phone was able to pair with the speaker.

Comment: This should be the same while pairing with Ubuntu "Blutooth indicator > New device" but it may be that the speakers do not support multple devices...  you may try with the "Speaker Connect" mode to see if that helps. Unfortunately the available online documentation is too poor to say, and I can't test this myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "Speaker Connect" mode? I don't see it in Ubuntu's bluetooth thing. The speaker supports up to 3 connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old AUX cable and was able to connect it that way. Still interested in a wireless solution if anyone has one.